# Comment moderation on custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, comments

I know that I can require all of the comments on my site to be moderated, but is there a way of forcing moderation for a specific custom post type (i.e. my CPT "species") whilst allowing instantaneous comments across the rest of the site?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Comment moderation is an option, and is retrieved like any other option:

```
get_option('comment_moderation');
```

the get_option function applies a filter before returning the value...

```
return apply_filters( 'option_' . $option, maybe_unserialize( $value ) );
```

So what you'll want to do is `add_filter('option_comment_moderation', 'check_moderable_post_types')` and in your `check_moderable_post_types` function, check to see if the current post's post type is species. If so, return 1, and if not return the $value that is passed to the function!

Edit: This *should* do the trick:

```
add_filter('option_comment_moderation', 'check_moderable_post_types');
function check_moderable_post_types($value) {
    if (get_post_type() == 'species') return 1;
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: Hi Matthew, thanks for this - works perfectly. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer doesn't work for me in WordPress 4.9.8. I figured it out with the help of `pre_comment_approved` hook.

Example:

```
add_filter('pre_comment_approved', 'misha_moderable_post_types', 10, 2);
function misha_moderable_post_types( $approved, $commendata ) {
    if ( get_post_type( $commendata['comment_post_ID'] ) === 'custom post type name' ){
        return true;
    }
    return $approved;
}
```